# How to use hyperledger fabric discovery service with CLI

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, service-discovery

How can I use the discover tool in Hyperledger Fabric 1.2 with CLI? I have the 1.2 binary and fabric files. I tried to execute discover command in the cli container in first-network, but I received an error saying "command not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build it locally via cloning the [repository](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric) and running **make discover**, or [download the binaries from nexus](https://nexus.hyperledger.org/content/repositories/releases/org/hyperledger/fabric/hyperledger-fabric/).
In the next releases it will be part of the fabric-tools image.

Comment: I do have discover in my binary, should I call discover command as I call peer command in the cli container? If I do that, I got an error message saying discover command not found. I also ran make discover, but I can't see a discover image

Comment: you need to get the discover command into the CLI container... use docker cp or something

Comment: I managed to get the command by specifying it in docker-compose-cli.yaml with this line: ../bin/discover:/usr/local/bin/discover